# Ssis connection with on premises systems

Tags: ssis

I have created a Virtual machine on Azure cloud. I want to figure out a mechanism of connecting Ssis with clients on-premises (non-cloud) SAP system. Is there any ssis utility that I can install that will breathe behind clients firewall and pass the data to Azure SQL database?

Comment: You have an Azure VM for running SSIS. You will use Azure SQL Database (hosted). The desire is to push data from client sites to the hosted database, preferably using your Azure VM's SSIS power?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called Microsoft Data Management Gateway for connecting from Azure to on-premise:
http://www.microsoft.com/nl-nl/download/details.aspx?id=39717

Comment: Billinkc- yes the desire is to push data from on premises systems by hooking into them through SSIs on VM and pushing data into the Vm azure database.